# Excluding rows with related values

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  url        | fieldname    | value
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  a,b,c      | RATE         | 45
----------------------------------------
  a,b,c      | PLAY         | 5
----------------------------------------
  a,b,c      | DATE         | 2013-05-20
----------------------------------------
  d,e,f      | PLAY         | 2
----------------------------------------
  d,e,f      | DATE         | 2013-01-01
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I exclude ALL rows with one particular (unknown!) value in the `url` column, IF one of the rows with the same `url` value has a particular (known!) value in the `fieldname` column?

As an example, how would I do if I wanted to exclude rows with `RATE` in `fieldname`, but also the "related" rows (those with the same value in the `url` column) -- so that it would return a table like this?:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  url        | fieldname    | value
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  d,e,f      | PLAY         | 2
----------------------------------------
  d,e,f      | DATE         | 2013-01-01
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Again, keep in mind that the `url` value should not have to be specified in the query.

Comment: No, these tables come from a database which is used in a C++ program (they were originally SQLite, too, but I had to migrate because SQLite frontends are crap..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "sets-within-sets" query.  I like using aggregation with the `having` clause, because it is the most general approach.

The following query gets the URLs you are interested in:

```
select url
from t
group by url
having sum(case when fieldname = 'RATE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

To get all the rows in the original table, you need to join back to it:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select url
      from t
      group by url
      having sum(case when fieldname = 'RATE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
     ) turl
     on t.url = turl.url
```

Comment: only thing keeping it from working was the "else 0; end" .... works if you go with "ELSE 0 END"

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work (second code block)! Although, I had to make a small correction: removing the semicolon on the `case when` part. --- EDIT, Drew beat me to it.